# Manually locking unique/shared boost lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

i was working on the reversed worker/consumer pattern. Between these 4 methods i will do write/read operations.

```
...
void beginWrite();
void endWrite();

void beginRead();
void endRead();
...
```

I only know for scoped shared/unique lock. So how is this done manually via shared/unique lock? So i would lock shared in beginRead and release in endRead. Or lock/release in another thread unique lock?

Comment: What type is the lock? `boost::shared_mutex`?

Comment: Just make sure that you unlock the lock in *all* circumstances (exceptions, I'm looking at _you_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost's shared locks have functions that perfectly corresponding to the functions you listed. They are `lock` (get exclusive lock), `unlock` (release exclusive lock), `lock_shared` (get shared lock), and `unlock_shared` (release shared lock).